# Why is there not a delay within my Unity code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on two scripts: one that destroys a target after two seconds after contact has been made, and another that activates the next target. Although I have used coroutines and invokes for both, I still am not getting a delay. Any thoughts? The "FootballContact" script is connected to the football and the "TargetActivate1" script is attached to the first target

[Football Contact Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz1bc.jpg)

[TargetActivate1 Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFtpV.jpg)

I tried to use a coroutine to delay the target from being destroyed, but my new "TargetActivate1" script makes it so the activation of the targets overlaps with when the target is destroyed--making the destroying/activation process instant. As a result, I tried using that same coroutine function on the new script--it didn't work. The internet said I can't have two coroutines running at the same time, so I changed the coroutine to an "invoke". It still does not work and I'm very confused as to what to do next. I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Because a coroutine runs independently. So you sent off a routine to wait for a bit and do nothing while you move onto the next line

Comment: Please type your scripts into your question, don't link to them. And *especially* don't link to images of code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IEnumerator for both scripts to make it easier

The reason it isn't working is because you need to place the code, that you would like to run after the delay, within the IEnumerator function.

How coroutines work is that when you call StartCoroutine the IEnumerator function will be called and will be run independently of the method in which you called it. So, any code underneath the StartCoroutine will continue as normal.

For you FootballContact script, for example, the code should look like this:

```
private IEnumerator Delay(){
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
  DestroyObject(target);
}
```

Comment: Cody, you are an ABSOLUTE GODSEND. I've been trying to figure this out for HOURS and can't believe the solution was THAT easy! Thank you SO much!!!

Comment: Why not just issue destroy with a second parameter of the delay?

Comment: Haha thank yoou But like what others have said, you can use the second parameter of the Destroy method to wait a certain amount of time before destroying. Obviously this is only useful if you're using the delay to just destroy something, and not doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The destroy code itself has a delay, but if you want a more professional method, read about `Async`.

```cs
Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
```

---

Asynchronous example:

```cs
private async void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Before Wait!");
    await Task.Delay(2000); // in milliseconds.
    Debug.Log("After Wait!");
}
```